# Colimit of discrete diagram (coproduct) is the tensor product

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory, limits-colimits

Let $C$ be the category of unital, commutative, $k$ algebras, where $k$ is a field.

Given a discrete category $I$, with two elements, let $F: I \to C$ be a functor.

Denote $I(i_1) = A_i$ for $i = 1,2$.

> What's the colimit of this diagram?

My attempt:

The colimit, $colim_I F$, is $A_1 \otimes A_2$.

It can be shown that the two projections $p_i:  A_i \to  A_1 \otimes A_2$ given by $p_1(a_1) = a_1 \otimes 1, p_2(a_2) =  1 \otimes a_1$ are ring homomorphisms using the fact that $(a_1 + b_1, 1)$ ~ $ (a_1 , 1) + (b_1, 1)$.

So now I need to prove that given $W \in C$ and maps $f_i: A_i \to W$ in $C$, there is a unique map $f: A_1 \otimes A_2 \to W$ s.t $f \circ p_i = f_i$.

The uniqueness part seems straightforward to me. It is the issue of existence that I'm having trouble with:

I want to define $f$ using elements of the basis to $A_1 \otimes A_2$. Let's say that $\{e_j: j \in J\}$ and $\{f_k: k \in K\}$ are bases for $A_1, A_2$ respectively. Define $f(e \otimes f) = f_1(e)f_2(f)$ so that $f \circ p_i = f_i$ holds. It is straighforward that $f$ preserves the multiplicative structure on $A_1 \otimes A_2$ and the multiplicative identity. How can I show it preserves the additive structure? Is this the correct definition for $f$?

Comment: Do you know the universal property of the tensor product of vector spaces?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan not well enough; I assume you mean the a linear map out of the tensor product is the same as a bilinear map out of the product? If so, can you please explain, or reference, why this is? I see that this solves this completely, though I have not learned why this universal property holds; it is mentioned in my notes though, with no further explanation.

Comment: It's actually the definition of a tensor product